# ui-grid - how set display name for select column when select-all enabled?

Tags: ui-grid

I have a grid where I want a display name shown in the select-all cell, in addition to the checkmark.  Yes, this is unconventional.  Selecting rows in this grid is not really selecting rows, but taking a visible action on each row.  Select-all causes the action on all rows of course - an unselect all undoes the action.  I don't see how to do show a display name in the column header.  We are using ui-grid 4.0.6.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the ui-grid default tempalte by doing like below:

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/selectionSelectAllButtons', '<div>...Your template...</div>');
```

Note: You also need to override the ui-grid CSS, otherwise you cannot display your column name correctly.

Here it can display column name with 'All' without modifying any styles.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I currently have the checkmark and the heading text I desired by simply adding the text prior to the </div> in that template.  The next step would be to prevent the text from going gray when not all rows are selected.  Perhaps that is what you meant with the CSS hint.  However, I have been directed to remove the ability to select/unselect all - but simply have my text as the column heading.  Now I have to figure out how to do that in a grid that doesn't allow select all.